# Unable to bind scroll on window after unbind using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using `window.scroll` event to load content on div just when buttom of scroll reached.

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
       $(window).unbind('scroll');
       loadMoreCommentsOnArticle();
   }
});

  function loadMoreCommentsOnArticle(){
                $(window).bind('scroll');
                var dynamicData = fetchData();
                $('#parentElement').append(dynamicData);
}
```

scroll is not binding after once bind initially. maybe by $(window).unbind('scroll'). But i am trying to bind scroll again using $(window).bind('scroll'); but it is not working.

By not using $(window).unbind('scroll') . Scroll event is firing ample of times in no time.

I am using this way according to Rory

```
var $window = $(window);
function windowScroll() {
  if ($window.scrollTop() + $window.height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
    window.off('scroll');
    loadMoreCommentsOnArticle();
  }
}
 $window.scroll(windowScroll);
```

Comment: don't write bind inside the function write it inside $(document).ready();

Comment: And one more thing is loadMoreCommentsOnArticle() this function is not at all called !!

Comment: @Sindhoor document.ready isn't necessarily required in this sample as it's all hinged off the `window`. Also the function is called within the `scroll` handler when the `if` condition is met.

Comment: ok now you edited the question before called function name was different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because when you re-bind the scroll event in `loadMoreCommentsOnArticle()` you're not providing a function to run. You can solve the issue by extracting the scroll logic out to it's own function to make binding/rebinding easier.

Also note that `bind()` and `unbind()` are deprecated. You should use `on()` and `off()` instead.

```js
var $window = $(window);

function windowScroll() {
  if ($window.scrollTop() + $window.height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
    $window.off('scroll');
    loadMoreCommentsOnArticle();
  }
}

$window.scroll(windowScroll);

function loadMoreCommentsOnArticle() {
  $window.on('scroll', windowScroll);
  $('#parentElement').append(fetchData());
}

function fetchData() {
  console.log('loading data...')
  return '<div>More data...</div>';
}
```

```css
#parentElement div {
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentElement">
  <div>Some data...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Scroll is not invoke at all.

Comment: window.scrollTop is not a function

Comment: It's `$window`, not just `window`

Comment: window.off is not a function

Comment: ... again `$window`, not `window`. Why not just copy/paste the code from the answer?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate any issues with the above code, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/4eemoy9g/